# Не могу нажать на кнопку с помощью selenium: Other element would receive the click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется сайт такого вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вверху видно кнопки, на которые у меня не получается нажать

Вот сам код

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#charts')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal').click()
driver.save_screenshot('screencoin.jpg')
driver.quit()
```

Вот сам код этой кнопки взятый из сайта

```
<g class="highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal" style="cursor:pointer;" transform="translate(122,0)"><rect fill="#f7f7f7" class=" highcharts-button-box" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="22" rx="2" ry="2"></rect><text x="8.4296875" style="font-weight:normal;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="14">1d</text></g>
```

Пытался еще подставить другой класс

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('highcharts-button-box').click()
```

В итоге получаю вот такие ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crypto.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal').click()
  File "/Users/milkiweed/Desktop/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 555, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/Users/milkiweed/Desktop/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 955, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Users/milkiweed/Desktop/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/milkiweed/Desktop/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64
```

и еще одну на другую попытку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crypto.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_class_name(' highcharts-button-box').click()
  File "/Users/milkiweed/Desktop/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/milkiweed/Desktop/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/milkiweed/Desktop/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/milkiweed/Desktop/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <rect fill="#f7f7f7" class=" highcharts-button-box" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="22" rx="2" ry="2"></rect> is not clickable at point (153, 64). Other element would receive the click: <text x="8.4296875" style="font-weight:normal;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="14">...</text>
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Требуется нажать на эту кнопку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая ваша ошибка `Compound class names not permitted` говорит о том, что искать методом `find_element_by_class_name()` можно только элементы с одним классом. У вас их два: `class="highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal"`. Чтобы искать такие элементы пользуйтесь поиском по css селекторам или xpath.

Вторая ошибка `Element <...> is not clickable at point (153, 64). Other element would receive the click` говорит о том, что эелемент перекрыт другим. По перекрытым эелементам хромдрайвер не разрешает кликать.

Попробуйте кликнуть по элементу `text`. Приведу пример, но не ручаюсь, что мой xpath будет работать всегда, так как нужно видеть весь DOM, чтобы составить оптимальный.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//g[@class="highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal"]/text[text()="1d"]'
).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, я бы предложил сделать assert на то, что кнопка есть и находится в кликабельном состоянии, а во-вторых, никогда не стоит искать по классу, если только этот класс не один-разъединственный вот специально для этого элемента. Нужно искать по наиболее уникальным параметрам. В данном случае, я бы обратил внимание на text. В крайнем случае, в отдельной переменной укажите x-path (либо css-селектор, если больше нравится) кнопки и уже через него ищите ее и кликайте.